# Inconsistent behaviour after upgrading web app from WAS 6.1 to WAS 8

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, websphere-8, ibm-was

We have recently upgraded an application from WAS 6.1 to WAS 8 Server. The application has been working fine with WAS 6 but has random issues where data does not get inserted to database via hibernate. We are getting below error multiple times in logs but application executes flawlessly.

```
SystemErr     R FATAL ERROR:  'java.lang.NullPointerException' :null
```

we could not get to the exact code/cause which throws this error as it does not print any stack trace.
The error itself is not being thrown from java code as it works perfectly in debug mode. Is it a websphere related error or something else ? Can it be the cause of data not getting inserted properly.

Application uses Hibernate 2.1.8 for transactions with cglib-full 2.0.2 and oracle 10g database.

We have already tried debug mode in log4j for hibernate and other things.
We also tried setting log level to finest in WebSphere Admin Console but it did not help either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check both `SystemOut.log` and `SystemErr.log`? WebSphere components usually print full stack trace when logging errors, so I'd rather suspect your code or some library you are using. You really have to narrow this a bit, based on your logging, as in the form like this it will be very hard to pin point your problem.

Comment: We were able to resolve the NullPointerException by rebuilding our code with JDK 1.6 and removing few old class files which had compatibility issues with JDK 1.6. But the issue still remains :(